# Parameterization using CSV to JSON (Different data types)

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter

I am trying to parameterize a Webservice from a CSV file to JSON.

In my CSV file ([screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUB8b.jpg)), the values I need are in the 6th row as shown. I get this error:

> Failed not able to load
>
> passing blank values (Debug)...

When I try to pass the values from the 8th row, the operation completes successfully.

But in my case, how can I provide or convert the values to String or Int for parsing them as JSON using a preprocessor?

I need to convert the values like this: 6th-8th row from the CSV file to JSON and then pass to Jmeter-JSON request. We use MONGODB.

Is this possible to covert in jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot keep JSON in CSV because CSV is [comma-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) and commas are widely in JSON.

If you cannot change the source data format I can only suggest switching to Excel and reading the data from the cells using [Apache POI API](https://poi.apache.org/)

More information:

- [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)
- [How to Implement Data Driven Testing in your JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-implement-data-driven-testing-in-your-jmeter-test)